# How to put a tooltip to a button for enabling and disabling in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to put a tooltip to a button for enabling and disabling in WPF. I have mentioned the tried code below. But My tried code does not solve my problem. I have no idea should I use the separate property for this.

Code:

```
<dc:GeometryButton 
   Grid.Column="11"
   Command="{Binding Path=GeneratePrintTemplateFilesCommand}"
   Geometry="{StaticResource {x:Static dc:Geometries.Print}}"
   ToolTip="{Binding  Path=GeneratePrintTemplateFilesFeatureToolTip}"
   Style="{StaticResource FormBuilderClient_TopToolbarGeometryButton_Style}"/>
```

I need your help to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to: 1. Show a tool tip or 2. Enable/disable the button from the tooltip popup box?

Comment: We need to have the code-behind before we can help you

Comment: In addition to michal's two interpretation s there's at least another. Maybe the tooltip should have different content if the button is disabled. Please edit and clarify in the question what you mean.

Comment: If the idea is to disable the button from some button or checkbox in a tooltip then you should consider a context menu rather than tooltip. But this would be an unusual requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Same tool tip when disabled

If you want to show the *same* tool tip for both the enabled and disabled state of the button, you have to set the `ShowOnDisabled` property of the `ToolTipService` to `True` on your button.

```
ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
```

### Different tool tips through binding

If want to show different tool tips by changing the bound property `GeneratePrintTemplateFilesFeatureToolTip` in your view model on button click e.g. in your `GeneratePrintTemplateFilesCommand`, the first solution also works. However, you must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in this case, otherwise the button will not get notified of the changed tool tip text.

### Different tool tips with style

An alternative for showing *different* tool tips for the enabled and disabled states of your button is to add a trigger to the `Style` of the button and make it depend on the `IsEnabled` property. You can merge this with your existing style. Note that I use two different properties to bind to, one for enabled and one for disabled. In practice, you would rather use static resources here, instead of properties on a view model, because they do not change here.

```
<Style x:Key="FormBuilderClient_TopToolbarGeometryButton_Style"
       TargetType="{x:Type dc:GeometryButton}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type dc:GeometryButton}}">
   <Setter Property="ToolTip"
           Value="{Binding GeneratePrintTemplateFilesFeatureToolTipEnabled}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
               Value="False">
         <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                 Value="{Binding GeneratePrintTemplateFilesFeatureToolTipDisabled}"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Make sure to remove the tool tip property from the button control itself and add the `ShowOnDisabled` property setting from above., otherwise your tooltip either will not change or not be displayed in disabled state.

```
<dc:GeometryButton Grid.Column="11"
                   Command="{Binding Path=GeneratePrintTemplateFilesCommand}"
                   Geometry="{StaticResource {x:Static dc:Geometries.Print}}"
                   ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                   Style="{StaticResource FormBuilderClient_TopToolbarGeometryButton_Style}"/>
```